# Convert base64 to Image in Python

Tags: python, image, base64

I have a mongoDB database and I recover base64 data which corresponds to my Image.

I don't know how to convert base64 data to an Image.

Comment: How was the image put into the database? Once you know that, just reverse the process.

Comment: the image come from Android device.

Comment: the android convert the image in base64 and store it into the database. my task is to recover these data and convert them to an image

Comment: i think you have just to decode your data using `base64.b64decode` and write it to a file and you will have your image .

Comment: @Karl I don't think you understood my comment.

Comment: what do you mean by "write it to a file"?

Comment: I actually used base64.b64decode but it gives me a String, not an Image

Comment: What's an "Image"? Like a `Image` from PIL or something?

Comment: Sounds like the android is *not* just converting the image file data to base64 and storing that into the database. If it were, then using `base64.b64decode` would reverse the process and recover the image file. Note that image file formats often include headers and other metadata -- not just raw pixel information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to use that in a webpage, you can just put the base64 encoded image into a HTML file.

[See wikipedia for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 23):

Building on Christians answer, here the full circle:

```
import base64

jpgtxt = base64.encodestring(open("in.jpg","rb").read())

f = open("jpg1_b64.txt", "w")
f.write(jpgtxt)
f.close()

# ----
newjpgtxt = open("jpg1_b64.txt","rb").read()

g = open("out.jpg", "w")
g.write(base64.decodestring(newjpgtxt))
g.close()
```

or this way:

```
jpgtxt = open('in.jpg','rb').read().encode('base64').replace('\n','')

f = open("jpg1_b64.txt", "w")
f.write(jpgtxt)
f.close()

# ----
newjpgtxt = open("jpg1_b64.txt","rb").read()

g = open("out.jpg", "w")
g.write(newjpgtxt.decode('base64'))
g.close()
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
import base64 
png_recovered = base64.decodestring(png_b64text)
```

'png_b64text' contains the text from your mongoDB image field.

Then you just write "png_recovered" to a file:

```
f = open("temp.png", "w")
f.write(png_recovered)
f.close()
```

Just replace 'png' with the correct format.

Comment: it doesn't display me an image but a string

Answer (score 1):

Your image file(jpeg/png) is encoded to base64 and encoded base64 string is stored in your mongo db. First decode the base64 string

```
import base64
image_binary=base64.decodestring(recovered_string_from_mongo_db)
```

Now image_binary contains your image binary, write this binary to file

```
with open('image.extension','wb') as f:
    f.write(image_binary)
```

Where extension is your image file extension.