# Save image in base64 django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I'm working on my app (hybrid) and on the register page I have to send all the data to an API made with Django Rest Framework.

The problem is that the only way I can send the profile picture is in **base64 encoded string**. But I need the image in jpg on my server. Anyone knows how can I do this?

This is my api View:

```
 class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        error = 0
        data = request.data

        try:
            name = data['name']
        except KeyError:
            name = ""

        try:
            last_name = data['last_name']
        except KeyError:
            last_name = ""

        # IMAGE IN BASE64    
        try:
            profile_picture = data['profile_picture']
        except KeyError:
            profile_picture = ""

        try:
            username = data['username']
        except KeyError:
            username = ""

        try:
            created_user = User.objects.create(
                first_name = nombre,
                last_name = last_name,
                username = username
            )

            # created_user.set_password(password)
            created_user.save()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=created_user)
        except IntegrityError:
            error = 1

        return Response(error)
```

And this is my Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'groups')
```

Is there any way to take the base64 and **create a jpg**?

Comment: I found solution for myself with the next code on stack - [http://stackoverflow.com/](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6781529/795622)

Comment: The `try`/`except KeyError:`s are a bit overkill.  You can simply use the `get()` method and provide the empty string as default value: `name = data.get('name', '')`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`base64.decodestring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.decodestring):

```
from base64 import decodestring

fh = open("imageToSave.jpeg", "wb")
fh.write(str(base64_string).decode('base64')) # or fh.write(decodestring(base64_string))
fh.close()
```