# How can I convert this String to an img .jpg from this Base64?

Tags: python, django, server, base64

I'm working with django, and when I recived an encode image by Base64, I recive like this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvuin.png)

How can I decode and save on an image .jpg?
I think the problem is that it start with {"imgB64":" and end with }'
I been worked with Base64 before and doesn't have this begining and ending, What do you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert base64 to Image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368669/convert-base64-to-image-in-python)

Comment: it can be JSON data with Python's dictionary which has key `"imgB64"` and value `"image in Base64"`. So you can convert JSON back to Python's dictionary and get value from dictionary. OR simply cut off this parts (`{"imgB64":"` and `"}`) and keep only data which you can convert from Base64 to image.

Comment: raze92 - It isn't the same problem, I can't convert to base64 using decodestring() or b64decode

Comment: furas - Do you know how to convert JSON back to Python's dictionary? I tried the second one option and it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: what means doesn't work ? can't you slice it ? ie. `data = data[11:-2]` and later use code from link in first comment. But first `print()` data to see if it is sliced correctly.

Comment: `python_dict = json.loads(data.decode())` or even withouth `.decode()` - `python_dict = json.loads(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import json

myImage = b'{"imgB64":"something"}'
parsed_json = (json.loads(myImage))

print(parsed_json['imgB64'])
```