# Download an image from google using direct path (not link)

Tags: python

Google images have this weird path element, which when typed into a browser will directly bring you to the image (i.e.

data:image/png;base64,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

brings you to a picture of the Apple company logo). Is there any way to download an image given this link?
Requests and requests_html cannot access this type of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the base64 encoding of the image. If you just take that as a string and save to disk after decoding base64, it will save correctly as a png.

from this answer:

```
# your string is 
img_data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM4AAAD1CAMAAAAvfDqYAAAAflB'...

# For both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x
import base64
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img_data))
```

[Convert string in base64 to image and save on filesystem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Those letters and number ARE the image. Literally. It's just base64 encoded.

So one thing you could do is import the base64 library to convert that string into an image which you could then save to disk.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37767000/1831109